# Error Message from DnsResolver.pm after removing IPv6

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, debian-wheezy, spamassassin

After removing IPv6 (to get KVM working) from `/etc/network/interfaces`, I'm getting lately the following error:

> error creating a DNS resolver socket: Network is unreachable at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/DnsResolver.pm line 235.

Any idea on how to fix this problem? I'm using Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out the ip6 from */etc/resolv.conf* solved the issue.

```
# nameserver config
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 213.133.99.99
#nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a111::add:9898
#nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a102::add:9999
#nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a0a1::add:1010
```